# Drupal: adding autocomplete to textfield for custom content type

Tags: drupal, autocomplete

I've added a custom content type, "Property" (as in, a building). I've added a text field to this content type. At */admin/structure/types/manage/property/fields*, this field is displayed as:

```
Label: Property Region
Machine Name: field_property_region
Field Type: Text
Widget: Text field
```

When an admin user goes to add a new Property, I'd like this field to display autocomplete suggestions using existing values from other Property nodes. However, **no autocomplete circle is displayed in the text input when I load the form page, and no suggestions are displayed when input is entered**.

Here's what I've done (in *modules/custom/hr_misc.module*):

```
function hr_misc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == "property_node_form"){
    $form['field_property_region']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'hr_misc/autocomplete/property_regions';
    dpm($form['field_property_region']);
  }

}
```

When I load the form (at */node/add/property*), the dpm() debug output is displayed and includes the #autocomplete_path value as expected.

```
function hr_misc_menu() {
  $items['hr_misc/autocomplete/property_regions/%'] = array(
    'page callback'     => '_hr_misc_autocomplete_property_regions',
    'access callback'   => TRUE,
    'page arguments'    => array(3),
    'weight'            => 1,
    'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Most of the examples I've seen don't include the wildcard or passing page_arguments. One did, and it makes sense to me that it should, so I've included it. I've tried both approaches. If I visit

```
http://mysite/hr_misc/autocomplete/property_regions/Lond
```

I see the JSON output:

```
{"London":"London"}
```

The JSON is produced by the following function:

```
function _hr_misc_autocomplete_property_regions($string)
{
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'property')
    ->fieldCondition('field_property_region', 'value', '%'. $string.'%', 'LIKE');

  $result = $query->execute();
  $nodes = $result['node'];

  // Get all fields attached to a given node type
  $fields = field_info_instances('node', 'property');

  // Get id of body field
  $field_id = $fields['field_property_region']['field_id'];

  // Attach a field of selected id only to get value for it
  field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));

  $items = array();
  foreach ($nodes AS $nid => $node) {
    $region = $node->field_property_region[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $items[$region] = $region;
  }
  print drupal_json_output($items);
  exit();
}
```

I'm at a loss. There are loads of articles on adding autocomplete fields, and they all seem to say that this is all you need. Do I need to add something else? The "author" field of my node autocompletes just fine, and I'm not seeing any errors (JS or PHP).

Comment: You're targeting the wrong element, it'll be something like `$form['field_property_region][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path']`. Have a quick read through http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784

Comment: @Clive - thanks, but no dice.

Comment: Maybe `$form['field_property_region][LANGUAGE_NONE]['value']['#autocomplete_path']`? It'll be whichever of the elements in the Devel output has a type of `textfield`

Comment: @Clive - still no luck I'm afraid. Between the arrays `['und']`, `['und'][0]`, and `['und'][0]['value']`, only the last one has a `type` item, and its value is indeed `textfield`. However, altering that array such that its dpm() output includes `#autocomplete_path (String, 37 characters ) hr_misc/autocomplete/property_regions` doesn't appear to affect the rendered HTML input in any way. However, altering `['und'][0]['value']['#description']` does alter the text under the field as expected.